# (iOS) What does kbViewRecoverNormalState means?

Tags: xcode, ios6, callstack, ipa, symbolicatecrash

We have this crash in our app that has this kind of log.

```
"date= 2013-02-03 07:12:17 +0000;
buildVersion = 1.0.0;
model = iPhone;
systemName = iPhone OS;
systemVersion = 5.1.1;
timeSpent = 1008.14;
uid = 63743f3790afda4d3bffc7beb8877fa9cfbfedfe;
reason = -[__NSCFType kbViewRecoverNormalState]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdd1dfe0;
stackTrace = 
(
    0 CoreFoundation 0x371288a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186
    1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x34e2d259 objc_exception_throw + 32
    2 CoreFoundation 0x3712ba9b -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 174
    3 CoreFoundation 0x3712a915 ___forwarding___ + 300
    4 CoreFoundation 0x37085650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
    5 SogouInputIPhone4.dylib 0x01a1982b -[AppStateMonitor exitSogouInputMethod] + 190
    6 SogouInputIPhone4.dylib 0x01a196e5 -[AppStateMonitor didEnterBackground] + 20
    7 Foundation 0x3798d4ff __57 -[NSNotificationCenteraddObserver:selector:name:object:] _block_invoke_0 + 18
    8 CoreFoundation 0x370f4547 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 70
    9 CoreFoundation 0x37080097 _CFXNotificationPost + 1406
    10 Foundation 0x379013eb -[NSNotificationCenterpostNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    11 UIKit 0x30e6c255 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] +792
    12 UIKit 0x30dfceff -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2094
    13 UIKit 0x30dfc567 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 54
    14 UIKit 0x30dfbf3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5826
    15 GraphicsServices 0x3383e22b PurpleEventCallback + 882
    16 CoreFoundation 0x370fc523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__+ 38
    17 CoreFoundation 0x370fc4c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
    18 CoreFoundation 0x370fb313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
    19 CoreFoundation 0x3707e4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
    20 CoreFoundation 0x3707e36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    21 GraphicsServices 0x3383d439 GSEventRunModal + 136
    22 UIKit 0x30e2acd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
    23 MyApp 0x0014506f _mh_execute_header + 295023
    24 MyApp 0x000ff058 _mh_execute_header + 8280
);"
```

That is a custom crash log that is not symbolicated when we migrated to Xcode 4.5.

My  question is, what is `kbViewRecoverNormalState` means? What class calls this selector? Since we can't read the stack trace clearly, we don't have any idea about this.

And is there any possible solution for this uninformative call stack? It is working on the device if it is connected to Xcode (debug/release). But when release on iTunes and/or created an `IPA` file, it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are test your app in jailbroken device.

`SogouInputIPhone4.dylib 0x01a1982b -[AppStateMonitor exitSogouInputMethod]`

Its the SogouInputIPhone4 which cause the crash

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks! We can ignore the crash then! :D